# select statement + join n' stuff

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM LiveStreams l 
INNER JOIN Friendships f ON f.Sender = l.Sender 
                         OR f.Sender = l.Recipient 
                         OR f.Recipient = l.Sender 
                         OR f.Recipient = l.Recipient 
WHERE l.Sender = @SomeUser OR l.Recipient = @SomeUser
```

My attempt for now ^

So, what im trying to do here is get all the streams from (livestreams table) of all the friends of a given @SomeUser. We can know the friends by using this query:

```
SELECT 
  Id, 
  CASE
    WHEN Sender = @UserName THEN Recipient 
    ELSE Sender 
  END AS Friend, 
  IsPending, 
  DateTime 
FROM Friendships 
WHERE (Sender = @UserName 
OR Recipient = @UserName) 
AND IsPending = @IsPending;
```

Given a @SomeUser, I would like to lookup his/her friends from the Friendships table having 3 columns (Id, Sender, Recipient) using single row (where the friend can be either the sender or the recipient) I would like to get all the friends and then get their speicifed stream from the livestream table (Id, Value, Sender, Recipient)

Sort of like the Facebook NewsFeed, When a @Person goes to the livestream pages, we will look for all the streams coming from his friends only. If his friends INITITED the stream or were sent the stream so they could be on either column too.. Sender or Recipient.

How can this be achieved? Ty

How can I do that?

**

### UPDATE:

**

THanks for the answers.

```
SELECT l.* LiveStreams l 
INNER JOIN Friendships f ON f.Sender = 'beta' OR f.Recipient = 'beta'
WHERE l.Sender = 'beta' OR l.Recipient = 'beta' OR 
   l.Sender = f.Recipient OR l.Sender = f.Sender OR 
   l.Recipient = f.Sender OR l.Recipient = f.Recipient
```

What doesn't work about this is that it still shows the feeds where beta is either the stream sender or the reciever, which I don't want because he's not a friend of himself.
is there a fix? Thanks again.

I don't know if this helps but that's how im getting the friend list of someone..

```
    "SELECT foo.* " +
    "FROM (SELECT Id, Sender, CASE " +
    "WHEN Sender = @UserName THEN Recipient " +
    "ELSE Sender " +
    "END AS UserName, IsPending, DateTime " +
    "FROM Friendships WHERE " +
    "Sender = @UserName " +
    "or Recipient = @UserName " +
    ") as foo " +
    "where foo.UserName = @FriendName;";
```

Comment: Why do live streams have a single recipient? And does a single recipient mean that only that recipient should be able to view the stream?

Comment: I store livestreams when any user posts a comment on someone elses wall.. so the sender is the sender and the recipient is the recipient, then when some other user logs into the livestream page, i'd like to filter out his friends from the livestream table (friends can be senders or recipients) and display the livestream value and id. :)

Comment: Is 'beta' not allowed to see his own streams? I added a new suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
SELECT l.* FROM LiveStreams l
INNER JOIN FriendShips f ON f.Sender = @SomeUser OR f.Recipient = @SomeUser
WHERE l.Sender = @SomeUser OR l.Recipient = @SomeUser OR
   l.Sender = f.Recipient OR l.Sender = f.Sender OR
   l.recipient = f.sender OR l.recipient = f.recipient
```

If the user must ONLY see friend streams:

```
SELECT l.* FROM LiveStreams l
INNER JOIN FriendShips f ON f.Sender = @SomeUser OR f.Recipient = @SomeUser
WHERE l.Sender <> @SomeUser AND l.Recipient <> @SomeUser AND (
   l.Sender = f.Recipient OR l.Sender = f.Sender OR
   l.recipient = f.sender OR l.recipient = f.recipient
)
```

Comment: I will, but I edited my original post if you could please take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM LiveStreams l  
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT  
    f2.Id,  
    CASE WHEN f2.Sender = @UserName 
         THEN f2.Recipient  
         ELSE f2.Sender END AS Friend,  
    f2.IsPending,  
    f2.DateTime  
  FROM Friendships f2 
  WHERE (@UserName IN (f2.Sender, f2.Recipient))  
  AND f2.IsPending = @IsPending) f ON 
                         (f.Sender    IN (l.Sender, l.Recipient)
                       OR f.Recipient IN (l.Sender, l.Recipient))  
WHERE @SomeUser IN (l.Sender, l.Recipient)
```

Comment: Hey Johan, thank you for the answer but this is giving me: Msg 207, Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'Sender'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'Sender'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'Recipient'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'Recipient'.

Comment: @user1027620, Zend does not like subqueries. I never liked zend-like frameworks, they;re too limiting.